# ASP.Net WebAPI app post data always null for json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Despite of including jsonformatter in global.asax file, the post method could not parse the json data as Model and always showing null.

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
```

I am using Fiddler to post the data and below is raw request:

```
POST http://localhost:50121/api/Store HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:50121
Content-Type: "application/json"
Content-Length: 84

{”quantity”:"4",“imagePath”:”http://localhost/”,“price”:"20.00"}
```

Model:

```
namespace StoreBackEnd.Models
{
    public class Subcategory
    {
        public string quantity { get; set; }
        public string imagePath { get; set; }
        public string price { get; set; }


       }
}
```

The Post method is:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Subcategory products)
    {
        var database = productsClient.GetDatabase("test");
        //IMongoCollection<Subcategory> collection = database.GetCollection<Subcategory>("entities");
        //collection.InsertOne(products);
        return new HttpResponseMessage() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Accepted };
    }
```

The products variable of Subcategory is always null.
I also tried using [FromBody] attribute but still variable is always null.

Can anyone suggest what am I missing? as the json also is well formatted.

Comment: have you checked the validity of your JSON? try JSONLint.com for this.. I copied over your json and got a couple of parsing errors.. could be why it doesn't work.

Comment: Try adding DataContract and DataMember attributes on your model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "double quotes" in your JSON don't look right.. Try following:

```
{"quantity":"4","imagePath":"http://localhost/","price":"20.00"}
```

Comment: The missing piece was charset:utf-8 with mistakes in json text request body